# Column Mean and SD after MICE Imputation

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I've run MICE on my dataset with m = 18, and I'm looking to identify the new mean and SD of a column with a pooled estimate as I wish to compare this against my original unadjusted dataset but can't quite figure out how to achieve this. I was wondering if anyone might have any advice on this?

So far, I've been able to calculate the mean or sd (replacing mean for sd in the code below) for each imputed dataset for that column using

```
library(mice)
aux_vart <- mice::quickpred(
nhanes,
mincor = 0.1
)
imp <- mice::mice(nhanes, pred = aux_vart, m = 16, meth = "pmm")
give_imp_n <- with(imp, expr = mean(bmi))
```

but when I try to pool these together, using:

```
give_pool_n <- mice::pool(give_imp_n)
```

I receive an error:

> Error in summarize(., m = n(), qbar = mean(.data$estimate), ubar = mean(.data$std.error^2), :
>
> Caused by error in `.data$estimate`:
> ! Column `estimate` not found in `.data`.

Comment: please give us a reproducible example

Comment: Apologies, done

Answer (score 0):

The `pool` function seems to require output from a linear regression. If you model your mean as an intercept-only regression, it seems to work:

```
give_imp_n <- with(imp, expr = lm(bmi~1))
mice::pool(give_imp_n)
# Class: mipo    m = 2 
#          term m estimate      ubar        b        t dfcom       df       riv    lambda       fmi
# 1 (Intercept) 2   26.292 0.5801967 0.326432 1.069845    24 3.419396 0.8439345 0.4576814 0.6266439
```